# Time consumption profiling

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know, is there such a tool in ROS that I can use it to profile the total duration of time taken (or time-complexity) by each node that I'm running.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28383/time-consumption-profiling/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're looking to perform more in-depth timing analysis of your nodes, you can run the node in [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). This will allow you to see the time usage of each function in your program, step by step. A node can be run in Valgrind by using a [launch-prefix](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-24**:
If I run Valgrind by using a launch-prefix, where do I check the output?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-24**:
Use `launch-prefix="valgrind --log-file=/home/your_user/valgrind.log` to log to that file. I would then suggest you open that file in a valgrind gui of some kind. I use Kcachegrind on Ubuntu.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-24**:
I've got a permission problem to open the file via Kcachegrind. When I check the generated logfile, it not a read-only file. Any hint for this..

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-24**:
Are  you running ROS as a different user?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-24**:
No, the same user.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-24**:
You could just do `chmod 775 valgrind.log` to change the permissions.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-24**:
It's not the case of having permission problem, I think, could be something else. Any other possibilities I can open that via  Kcachegrind?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2013-04-02**:
Valgrind is not a good solution unfortunately because it's effectively a virtual machine that runs a single thread. It greatly affects the way a process runs distorting the costs. @Thomas_D's suggestion of sysprof avoids this issue though.

**Comment by [kun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29796/kun/) on 2017-07-11**:
In `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/yourpackage`, run the command in bash: `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./yournode`, you will get the right log file in the same path, the file name looks like 'callgrind.out.8521', use `kcachegrind callgrind.out.8521` to open the log file.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2018-08-02**:
HI, thanks for information, I have added new wiki for using valgrind on ROS. Any contributions are welcome. http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Profiling%20roslaunch%20nodes

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you looking for the runtime of an executable? In this case start the node using the unix-tool "time" (see "man time"). If you are using launch files, have a look at the launch-prefix attribute of the "node" tag:

```
<node pkg="somepkg" type="somename" name="somename" launch-prefix="time">
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-24**:
With the above line, I won't be able to know how much time is used for each of nodes I've, right? I've tried it, and it gives only one "elapsed"(time elapsed i guess).

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-26**:
I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. What exactly do you want to measure? "time" gives you the duration a program is running from startup until shutdown.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-27**:
Yes, it is. Thanks anyway. Only that, I couldn't be able to differentiate which one belongs to which process/node?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-27**:
The -f option of time lets you print out arbitrary output. Have a look at time's man-page.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While Valgrind is nice I tend to use [sysprof](http://sysprof.com/) more often. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install sysprof
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2013-04-02**:
This avoids valgrind's vm & single thread distortions, and so in many cases is a much better option.

**Comment by [Roberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/6121/roberto/) on 2013-08-23**:
I am trying to use sysprof with my ros code, but unfortunately I don't get it to run on ubuntu 12.04 x64. Do you know if it is possible?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-08-23**:
I used sysprof yesterday when running ROS nodes and it worked when I used sudo.